# nasm x86 a way to calculate e^x

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, nasm

I wrote a code that works for calculating e^x: (where x is a float)

```
    mov ebx, x
    fld dword [ebx]
    fldl2e
    fmulp
    f2xm1
    fld1
    faddp
```

it uses f2xm1 which calculates 2^st0
but st0 can be only in range of <-1.0,1.0>

I wonder if there is a way to calculate e^x for a wider rande

Comment: For `a^x` with the *same* range, you'd just need `log2(a)` instead of `log2(e)` (which the CPU has built-in).  But anyway, the function you're looking for is called `pow`, search for that.  (With x87 if you want to use obsolete legacy x87 instructions for some reason, instead of SSE.)

Comment: okok and how could I load e? It is all for edu purposes :D

Answer (score 1):

> […] how could I load e? […]

- **Calculate it**.
  For example, you can approximate e<sup>−1</sup> using the [the sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Derangements)

  ```
  ⎲   n         k
  ⎳ k = 0   (−1)   /  k!
  ```

  It should be fairly easy to implement, so left as an exercise to you.
  Since you/we know 20! is the largest factorial storable in a 64‑bit integer you can set n = 20.
  There will be a certain margin of error though.
  [Other sums.](https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/E/06/ShowAll.html)
- **Deduce it**.

  1. Browsing through the instruction reference you’ll notice there are some “load [built-in] constant” FPU instructions.
     Particularly log<sub>2</sub>(e) is interesting, because it’s the solution to the equation 2<sup>x</sup> = e.
     All we need is to raise this value to the power of 2, 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(e)</sup>, and there we have it, Euler’s number.
  2. There are two x87 instructions raising a value to the power of 2, yet `fscale` will consider *only integer* exponents and, as you already know, `f2xm1` has a limited domain [−1.0, 1.0], but log<sub>2</sub>e is approximately 1.4426, so it’s not in the domain.
  3. Nevertheless, from the documentation of `f2xm1` we can learn it has the range [−0.5, 1.0].
     This range is influenced by the “minus one” operation it does, so if we isolate the 2<sup>x</sup>

     ```
     2ⁿ − 1 = z       ⇒        z ∊ [−0.5, 1.0]
         2ⁿ = z + 1   ⇒  (z + 1) ∊ [ 0.5, 2.0]
     ```

     we see “acceptable results” of 2<sup>x</sup> can be in the range [0.5, 2.0].
     What if instead of calculating e, we calculate e / 2?
     e / 2 is about 1.36 so it’s within the range [0.5, 2.0].

     ```
       2ⁿ = e

      2ⁿ     e
     ──── = ───
      2      2

     2ⁿ⁻¹ = 0.5 e
     ```
  4. This is what the following solution does:

     ```
     fld1          ; 1.0
     fld1          ; 1.0              1.0
     fld1          ; 1.0              1.0              1.0
     fldl2e        ; log₂(e)          1.0              1.0              1.0
     ; adjust exponent so it’s within domain of `f2xm1`
     fsubrp        ; 1.0−log₂(e)      1.0              1.0
     f2xm1         ; 2^(1−log₂(e))−1  1.0              1.0
     ; reverse “minus one” operation
     faddp         ; 2^(1−log₂(e)     1.0
     ; Now we have e / 2  ⇒  times 2¹  (2¹ = 2)
     fscale        ; 2^(1−log₂(e))*2¹
     fstp [result] ; (empty)
     ```

     NB:
     The FPU’s current rounding mode also affects the value of the constants loaded.
- **Store/retrieve it**.
  Any normal person, however, will simply store it somewhere and retrieve it with an appropriate `fld`.

  ```
  section .rodata
  e: dt 2.71828182845904523536
  ```

  Obviously, you’ll take that approach in any production program, if at all (see next, your actual task).

---

> I wonder if there is a way to calculate e^x for a wider [range.]

- Yes, there is.
  [How can I write a power function myself?](/q/2882706/)
  [An implementation specifically for e<sup>x</sup>.](/a/44970882)
- The basic idea is still the same as in your code:
  Using [logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations) we calculate x ⋅ log<sub>2</sub>e and then
  “reverse” the logarithm stuff by raising this value to the power of the chosen logarithm’s base, here two.
  **e<sup>x</sup> = 2<sup>x ⋅ log<sub>2</sub>e</sup>**
- However, “annoyingly” `f2xm1` and `fscale` have, as you already know, a limited domain.
  So what if *decompose* the exponent?
  When x is not in the domain of `f2xm1`, we cannot do 2<sup>x</sup> directly.
  Yet, remembering our [exponent rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Indices) we see the following relationship:
  2<sup>x</sup> = 2<sup>n + m</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup> ⋅ 2<sup>m</sup>.
  All we need is to find proper n and m so that

  - n + m = x *and*
  - `f2xm1`/`fscale` are usable.

  The ideal candidate is to choose *an integer* n for `fscale` and an m = x − n for `f2xm1`.
  We can calculate m with `fprem` using 1.0 as the divisor and `fscale` will already truncate x as part of its operation.
- Having all of that knowledge you should arrive at the [solution shown in the already linked answer](/a/44970882).
  It’s actually a generalized version of the above code.
  Note that this algorithm does not even require to load Euler’s number first and take the logarithm of it it using `fyl2x`, but we can load it directly using `fldl2e`.